# Can online servers read my /minebot commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a mod on my game (1.7.10), which allows me to automatically kill animals, mine and farm.

To activate it though, I must type in

```
/minebot kill or /minebot plant wheat
```

Can the online server read these commands that I'm inputting?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### No.

Minebot commands are intercepted by minebot. The server admin will not see any commands starting with `/minebot` or `/minebuild`. It will however see mistyped commands (`/minebt`).

It is possible to intercept tab completes of the first word, so if you type `/min<tab>` often the server owner might get suspicious.

In late 1.7 versions and in 1.8, as soon as you typed the first space after `/minebot`, you can safely use tab complete. It will not be sent to the server.

(PS: I'm the minebot author ;-))

Comment: If " the server owner might get suspicious", then that's not a *mod*, that's a *hack*... :p

Comment: Well, the server might forbid botting, which counts as a "hack" in this case. @JoãoMendes

Answer (score 0):

A server owner can see any command you input from looking at the server console or the server logs.

Comment: The creator of the mod in question answered this question conclusively over 17 hours ago, what did this answer add to the post?

Comment: As you are contradicting a well upvoted and accepted answer, it may be useful to provide evidence supporting this answer.